# Get property from an object in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Have to do some php coding but I am totally new to it. The question is I was trying to get a property value from an object called $mgm_member, this object is from wordpress plugin which records website's member info. First I use:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($mgm_member));
```

The results shows that this obeject has 37 properties and all of them have values. Than I tried use

```
var_dump($mgm_member->phone);
```

The result is null. I tried many other properties but only the first property of this object have value. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

well I suppose if the scope of "phone" is private var_dump will not be able to access and view it, is it? In my case, I can view all properties and their values using var_dump() function but when I tried to get one property it just doesn't work. However,I can get the first property "id" using the same code

```
echo $mgm_member->id;
```

That is really weird.

Comment: What is the scope of 'phone' if it has the word 'private' next to it you will need some function to access it.

Comment: First, just do `var_dump($mgm_member);`, don't run it through `get_object_vars()` because that turns it into an array (so your var_dump won't be as helpful).

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump(get_object_vars($mgm_member));` shows the object variables. If you are getting data with this line of code, you have data in your object.

You can access properties of a variable in your code with `$mgm_member->phone` - why not do so?

If you want to place the data into a variable you can use something like this:

```
$myVar=$mgm_member->phone;
```

but that defeats the purpose of OOP. Why not refer to it as exactly `$mgm_members->phone` all the way through your code?

Edit: As you point out, the property is `private` which means that only the object itself can use it. You *could* get around this by modifying the object, but this may be a nasty approach - it is private for a reason. Can you not use functions within the object to display the values? Alternately, is there a function you can use in the object to return you a clone of the object with different property attributes?

Comment: I surely want use $mgm_members->phone all the way through my code, but echo $mgm_members->phone shows nothing while I can see the value using  var_dump($mgm_member), only $mgm_members->id works.

Comment: Because our company actually bought this plugin, and the only thing that I know is I can get all required info by calling this object. Therefore, I think the best way is to contact their customer service for help or I need to find the file myself. Anyway, thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

As the property is 'private' you will need to **make a function to access and return it**.

A dump may display them but you WILL NOT be able to directly access a 'private' property.

```
class .... {

    public function getPhone()
    {
        return ($this->phone);
    }

}
```

then:

```
echo $mgm_member->getPhone();
```